# js or CSS is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, validation

I have a signup form in which i have 2 drop downs one is category and one is Gender. i have a validation.js which validates my signup form on not selecting any option in the drop down box. the validation for gender is working fine. But for category even though i select a category it displaying an error and its stopping the submission. This was working fine before after i changed my design that is CSS this problem is occurring.

This is my Signup.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Form</title>
<link href="CSS/Signup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/State.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Validate.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ageCount() {
var date1 = new Date();
var dob = document.getElementById("SnapHost_Calendar").value;
var date2 = new Date(dob);
var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
//Regex to validate date format (MM/dd/yyyy)
if (pattern.test(dob)) {
var y1 = date1.getFullYear();
//getting current year
var y2 = date2.getFullYear();
//getting dob year
var age = y1 - y2;
//calculating age
document.getElementById("txtAge").value = age;
doucment.getElementById("txtAge").focus();
return true;
}

}
EnableSubmit = function(val) {
var sbmt = document.getElementById("submit");

if (val.checked == true) {
sbmt.disabled = false;
} else {
sbmt.disabled = true;
}
};
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function capitalize(el) {
var s = el.value;
el.value = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
}
</script>


<body onLoad="addList()">

<jsp:include page="Header.jsp"></jsp:include><br />


<div id="signuphead">
<h1>Welcome to registration page</h1>
<br /> <br />
<h3>Enter your personal details here</h3>
</div>

<form action="RegisterServlet" method="post" name="Register"
id="signup" onSubmit="return validate()">
<div id="signuptable">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name* :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtFname" id="txtFname"
maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)" /><br /> <span
id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide your first name.</font></span> <span
id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid first name.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name* :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLname" id="txtLname"
maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)" /><br /> <span
id="errorLastNameMissing" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide your Last name.</font></span> <span
id="errorLastNameInValid" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid Last name.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender* :</td>
<td><select name="txtGender" id="txtGender">
<option value="unknown">Select your Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select><br /> <span id="errorMissingGender" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please select a Gender.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category* :</td>
<td><select name="txtCategory" id="txtCategory">
<option value="unknown">Select your Category</option>
<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>

</select><br /> <span id="errorMissingCategory" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please select a Category.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><script type="text/javascript" src="js/Calendar.js"></script>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Age :</td>
<td><input type=text name=txtAge id="txtAge" readonly
style="width: 20px; background-color: #D0D0D0; border: none" />yrs.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address* :</td>
<td><textarea rows="5" name="txtAddr" id="txtAddr" cols="30"></textarea><br />
<span id="errorMissingAddress" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid Address.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State* :</td>
<td><select
onchange="print_city('txtCity',this.selectedIndex);" id="txtState"
name="txtState"></select><br /> <span id="errorMissingState"
style="display: none;"><font color="red">*Please
select a state.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City* :</td>
<td><select name="txtCity" id="txtCity"></select> <script
type="text/javascript">
print_state("txtState");
</script><br /> <span id="errorMissingCity" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please select a city.</font></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pincode* :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtPin" id="txtPin" /><br /> <span
id="errorMissingPinCode" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide your Pincode.</font></span> <span
id="errorPinCodeInvalid" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid Pincode.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Choose your UserName* :</td>
<td><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <input
type="text" name="txtUsername" id="username">@gmail.com
<div id="status"></div> <script type="text/javascript"
src="js/check_user.js"></script> <span id="errorMissingUserName"
style="display: none;"><font color="red">*Please
provide your username.</font></span> <span id="errorUserNameInvalid"
style="display: none;"><font color="red">*Please
provide a valid username.Username can contain only alphabets
numbers and periods</font></span> <span class="status"></span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alternate e-Mail* :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" /><br />
<span id="errorMissingEmail" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide your emailId.</font></span> <span
id="errorEmailInvalid" style="display: none;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid emailId.</font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number :</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtStd" id="txtStd" maxlength="6"
style="width: 40px" />-<input type="text" name="txtPhone"
id="txtPhone" maxlength="8" /><br /> <span
id="errorStdCodeInvalid" style="visibility: hidden;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid std code.</font></span> <span
id="errorPhoneNoInvalid" style="visibility: hidden;"><font
color="red">*Please provide a valid contact no.</font></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mobile Number* :</td>
<td>+91-<input type="text" name="txtMobile" id="txtMobile"
maxlength="10" /><br /> <span id="errorMissingMobileNo"
style="display: none;"><font color="red">*Please
provide your mobile number.</font></span> <span id="errorMobileNoInvalid"
style="display: none;"><font color="red">*Please
provide a valid mobile number.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<p>
<font color="red">Note: All the fields marked with * are
mandatory.</font>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkAgree" onclick="EnableSubmit(this)" /><font
color="green"> I here by declare that the above data entered
by me is true to my knowledge.</font>
</p>
<br />

<div class="style2">
<table>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" id="submit" disabled
style="width: 80px; height: 40px">Submit</button></td>
<td><div class="divider"></div></td>
<td><button type="reset" style="width: 80px; height: 40px"
onClick="resetForm()">Reset</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Validate.js:

```
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var validationMessage = 'Please correct the following errors:\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display = 'none';
if (document.getElementById('txtGender').value == 'unknown') {
        validationMessage = validationMessage
                + '  - Please select a gender\r\n';
        document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display = '';
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('txtCategory').value == 'unknown') {
        validationMessage = validationMessage
                + '  - Please select a category\r\n';
        document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display = '';
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display = 'none';
    }
if (valid == false) {
        alert(validationMessage);
    }
    return valid;
}
```

And this is my Signup.css:

@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

```
#signuphead {
    color: #059BD8;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
    color: #059BD8;
    background-color: #E3F1F9;
    border-style: groove;
}

#signup {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E3F1F9;
}

#signuptable {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #059BD8;
    border-style: groove;
}

#note {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E3F1F9;
}

#thanks {
    width: 956px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I am confused because i dono whether my js has a problem as previous project with another CSS works fine, or it is a problem with the css itself
Kindly help in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like your code works fine here [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex3zc/)

Comment: As you told have posted part of form code. But this is working fine as  @navin given the fiddle also. So post your entire form, so that we can check it out clearly.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai As u said i have edited my post with the entire form please have a look...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/Ex3zc/1/ check the fiddle. I have updated all your code and it is working fine. Successful submit will take it to you yahoo site.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai you changed anything or you just posted as it is cos still its giving me the same error

Comment: i didn't change anything. working fine for me  in chrome. which browser you are using?

Comment: ie8 and mozilla firefox.

Comment: i checked in my homes computer as well but same error

Comment: checked the same in firefox, working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

The sample code you attached is working. Maybe you have another element which contains the same ID as the Category select.

Comment: No am sure there is no duplicate id as category

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is missing the closing  `</div>` tag before `form` tag closing.

I have updated the code. just see once.

[Plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRyVu3wCQlmqgNZchznR?p=preview)

Comment: no no its a big form so while pasting it on the stack i would have forgotten that div tag. However am using eclipse if i miss anything it will intimate me. I have that div tag in my project. Thats not the issue